# SQL Server OLE Automation Error 0x80042724

Tags: sql-server, hresult

This:

```
 declare
   @OLEfilesytemobject int,
   @OLEresult int,
   @OLEFolder int

execute @OLEresult = [master].[sys].sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject',     @OLEfilesytemobject
execute @OLEresult = sp_OAMethod @OLEfilesytemobject, 'CreateFolder', @OLEFolder, 'F:\PMT\ITM\'
```

Used to work just fine. As in it created a folder **'F:\PMT\ITM\'**. Now it doesn't, it would appear it's not even creating the FileSytemObject.

I'm getting this HResult:

> -2147211484

Which comes back as this error:

> OLE Automation Error Information   HRESULT: 0x80042724   Source:
>   ODSOLE Extended Procedure   Description: sp_OACreate usage:  ProgID
>   varchar IN, ObjPointerToBeReturned int OUT [, @OLE_server_type int].

I've googled the error code to death over the last couple of days, but can't find anything relevant.

Anyone have a clue?

Thanks